# Add extra information to exceptions

Tags: language-agnostic, exception

Assume I have method that reads customers from a csv file.

When reading the file an exception occurs (e.g. IOException or FormatException). In most cases the method can't do anything about the errors but it can add extra information like file name, line number etc.

The method's class got an IProgressAndErrorReporter dependency that is used to log/display the error.

**How do I report back to the caller that an error occured but that it is already taken care of?**

Currently I do it like this:

```
class CustomerReader
{
    private readonly IProgressAndErrorReporter mProgressAndErrorReporter;

    public bool TryReadCustomers() {
        try {
            ...
            return true;
        }
        catch (IOException err) {
            mProgressAndErrorReporter.ReportError(err, "Can't read file {0} bla bla");
            return false;
         }
    }
 }
```

(I do only catch "expected" exceptions, i.e. not InvalidOperation etc)
I works fine but in the type of data processing applications I usually work with the level above looks like:

```
public bool TryProcessData() {
    if (!customerReader.TryReadCustomers())
        return false;

    var orders = webOrderReader.ReadNewOrders());
    if (orders == null)
        return false;

    if (!orderCreator.TryCreateNewOrder(order))
    ...

}
```

To me it feels like going back to the time before exceptions.

Should I throw some kind of "AlreadyHandledException" instead with an empty catch clause at the top level?

Answer (score 1):

Don't go back to the old days, wrap it in a higher level exception instead. In this case, you should define ReadCustormerDataException and ReadNewOrderException for instance. This has the added benefit of creating very readable code. Creating a new Exception is not that hard, if your language has Inner Classes you could create a public inner class.

In the end, it depends on the use case if you should return a boolean, but I would suggest you would catch the self defined (checked) exception at the higher level method that actually requires the boolean and not before.

If your method is bound to fail in normal conditions, then don't throw exceptions but return a (self defined) result class. This will make sure you and your colleagues don't have to make sure that the debugger stops in your code at normal operation. Finally, if you have many exceptions that should not stop the application, you might want to deliver the result class to a listener instead of returning it at the end of a method.

PS only include extra information if you are sure that information exists (otherwise you end up generating an exception within the exception handling) - not nice (Error, error table not found is a favorite of mine).

Comment: Thanks for replying to this old question. Don't understand why I should create more custom exceptions. Whatever can be done (rollback, log whatever) has already happened. I just want to back out of the top level function in a clean way?

Comment: Creating logs and such does not change the inner workings of the application. While debugging a problem or during other maintenance, it is important to have semantically correct exceptions. In your example, you say that the exception has been handled, but that is only the case regarding logging and resource handling: the application is still in an exceptional state (you skip execution of important parts). This should be represented with a exception that represents that state.